# Unable to access elements from ng-included files

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to do the most simple of things, from a JSON I'm repeating a menu where a certain scroll destination is defined. On the same repeated element I set a directive and pass the destination as a parameter to my directive function. Inside this function all I'm trying to do is access the element but I can't get access to the element for some reason.

All I get is this:

```
[context: document, selector: "#skills"]
[context: document, selector: "#projects"]
[context: document, selector: "#about"]
[context: document, selector: "#form"]
```

When I should be getting something similar to this test I did:

```
[header#site-header.container-fluid.ng-scope, context: document, selector: "#site-header"]
```

All of these selectors I'm trying to access comes from ng-included files like this:

```
<div ng-include="'views/templates/skillset.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'views/templates/projects.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'views/templates/about.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'views/templates/form.html'"></div>
```

Could that be the problem? If so, how do I gain access to those selectors? 
I tried accessing them directly with like `$('#skillset')` but that yields the same result.

Could it also be a scope problem? Since the included files have their own scope, does seem odd since the directive itself is bound to the `core` module which is the parent scope of them all.

Example of included file:

```
<div id="skillset" class="container padding narrow" ng-controller="SkillsCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 fav-box" ng-repeat="skill in skillset.favorites">
      <img ng-src="{{skill.imageUrl}}" alt="{{skill.alt}}" class="fav-box__logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my JSON:

```
{
  "menu": {
    "skillset": {
      "scrollTo": "#skills"
    },
    "projects": {
      "scrollTo": "#projects"
    },
    "about": {
      "scrollTo": "#about"
    },
    "contact": {
      "scrollTo": "#form"
    }
  }
}
```

The markup:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="site-nav">
  <li ng-repeat="item in menu" class="menu-item text-center" 
      data-smooth-scroll="{{item.scrollTo}}">
  </li>
</ul>
```

My directive:

```
core.directive('smoothScroll', [function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var dest = $(attrs['smoothScroll']);
      console.log(dest);

    }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute of angular directive is not evaluated it terms of angular expressions unless you define a reference to it via isolated scope. Your directive should look like

```
core.directive('smoothScroll', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        smoothScroll: '='
    }
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var dest = scope.smoothScroll;
      //do smooth scroll
      console.log(dest);
    }
  }
}]);
```

Usage should be `data-smooth-scroll="item.scrollTo"` without curly braces

Comment: It throws this error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'item.scrollTo' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{item.scrollTo}}] starting at [item.scrollTo}}].

Comment: You don't need curly braces for expressions

Comment: Still getting the same output as before though :/

Comment: I get the scrollTo into the directive function but I can't access it via $(scope.smoothScroll); for some reason

Comment: The reason is pretty simple... `scope.smoothScroll` is a string.. according to your code containing only `'#skills'`, for example. do smooth scroll should do the trick of smooth scroll you have in your mind :)

Comment: I bet you'd like to learn more about https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "do smooth scroll"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81058/discussion-between-kirill-slatin-and-chrillewoodz).